# Angular5 - Preselect the default value in mat-select

Tags: angular, material-design, angular5

Good evening,
I'm working on a project in **Angular5**. In particular I have a material select (**mat-select**) that should select me a role of a user, the **mat-select** is composed like this:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Scegli un opzione" [formControl]="form.controls['Ruolo']"  [(ngModel)]="admin.Ruolo">
         <mat-option *ngFor="let key of keys" [value]="key">{{roles[key]}}</mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

In my reference typescript file, I have a formgroup that handles everything.
In fact, when I return the user data from the server I assign to the form control in this way:

```
this.form.controls.Id.setValue(result.Id);
this.form.controls.Nome.setValue(result.Nome);
this.form.controls.Cognome.setValue(result.Cognome);
this.form.controls.Ruolo.setValue(result.Ruolo);
this.admin = result;
```

The other values are all set correctly, but the problem happens to me for the **Ruolo** field, which is an enumerated (number).

This is original setting form group in constructor:

```
  this.form = this.fb.group({
        Id: [null],
        Nome: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)])],
        Cognome: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(15)])],
        Ruolo: [null, Validators.required],
    });
```

For complete the informations, this is my class and enum:

```
export class Admin {
     Id: number;
     Nome: string;
     Cognome: string;
     Ruolo: ERolesAdmin;
}
export enum ERolesAdmin {
    SuperAdmin = 1,
    Admin = 2
}
```

How can I make the mat-select understand that it should preselect that value?

Thx all.

Comment: up please, up please